# Google maps con buscador en mi sitio y con un solo destino?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Me gustaría poner en un sitio web que estoy desarrollando una sección que sea "como llegar" la cual tenga un buscador, en el cual solo buscaría el origen y el destino siempre seria el mismo. Lo que no se, es si hay alguna librería o algo similar ya desarrollada para este tipo de casos.

Lo que quiero es algo similar a los siguiente http://www.aa2000.com.ar/aeroparque/ComoLlego

Muchas gracias. Saludos

Comment: Tu quieres que el mapa marque la ruta desde un lugar que le indique al usuario en el buscador a un destino X.

Comment: A lo mejor esto te pueda servir (ya que no tienes código ni nada, no te voy a hacer la chamba) este un enlace directamente de la API de google maps, justo en un codigo parecido al que buscas:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DisplayingResults y este es el ejemplo de de ese codigo (Esta tambien en la API de Google maps)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para buscar el origen, tienes que usar la clase [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference), y para tenerla disponible tienes que haber cargado google maps especificando que también quieres la librería `places`

```
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&v=3&libraries=places&key=<API KEY>"></script>
```

**Dado que conoces el destino**, supongo que conoces sus coordenadas (lat y lng). Vamos a partir por asumir eso. También vamos a asumir que tienes una variable `map` que representa la instancia de tu mapa.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(....),
    destino = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
```

**Dado que tienes la clase Autocomplete**, tienes que instanciarla sobre un elemento contenedor. Por ejemplo:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input_buscador');
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

A la instancia del autocompletador tienes que añadirle un listener que detecte cuando la persona ha ingresado una dirección:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace(),
      origen = place.geometry.location;
});
```

A esta altura ya conoces el origen y el destino, por lo que puedes usar el ejemplo que figura en [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsService.route({
      origin: origen
      destination: destino
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
   });
```

Te dejo la tarea de ponerlo todo junto y de pasar las variables de un lado a otro. Por ejemplo, construyendo una función que espere como input el origen y el destino;